# VS 2017 no permite crear ramas de github

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, github

hace unas semanas cloné un repositorio de github y realicé mis modificaciones(sobre la rama master). Pero ahora que trato de subirla no me deja dice que no realiza una rama de seguimiento remota. Pero luego quiero crear una rama adicional y me manda lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Supuse que puede bloquear el permiso cuando no tengo la extensión de github en VisualStudio,pero traté de mandarla por comandos de consola de git y manda permiso denegado, aunque mi repositorio está como publico en internet

Comment: Puede estar público pero igual te va a pedir credenciales correctas. Actualiza la versión de Git y usa el credential manager

Comment: Bueno, al final copié los cambios a otra pc con windows8 x64. Por las pruebas e intentos que he realizado es más un problema de incompatibilidad de Git con windows7 más si descargo la última version de git el problema puede ser mayor. (aunque se pueden seguir desarrollando aplicaciones Desktop o web)usando windows7 x86 para NetCore en definitiva un dolor de cabeza. Solo por el tema capacidad en mi equipo no utilizo win10. La solución es usar por lo menos windows8 y de 64bits funciona incluso con Git 2.27.0 para la cuestión de permisos

Comment: Siempre puedes usar Win10 y modificar la configuración para quitarle todos los efectos innecesarios en presentación. No llega a la eficiencia de Win7 pero se acerca lo suficiente. Sólo digo...